# NRF24 receiving data while turned off

Tags: arduino-nano

The code to set up the nrf24 is from Electronoobs. The further if-clauses are suposed the drive a motor. The problem I am facing is, that if ther is no data transmission (emitter turend off; or receiver antenna unplugged) the Arduino-Nano-Chip is receiving random values, but there should not be anything at all. I need something which sets the variables left/right to 512 as long as there is no data transmission, when the remote/controller is turned off for example.

```
//Emitter-Code
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

//const uint64_t my_radio_pipe = 0xE8E8F0F0E1LL; //Remember that this code should be the same for the receiver
const uint64_t my_radio_pipe = 0xE8E80000E1LL; //Remember that this code should be the same for the receiver

RF24 radio(9, 10); //CSN and CE pins

// The sizeof this struct should not exceed 32 bytes
struct Data_to_be_sent {
  byte ch1; 
  byte ch2;
};

Data_to_be_sent sent_data;



void setup()
{
  radio.begin();
  radio.setAutoAck(false);
  radio.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS);
  radio.openWritingPipe(my_radio_pipe);  
  sent_data.ch1 = 119;
  sent_data.ch2 = 58;
}

/**************************************************/


void loop()
{
  /*If your channel is reversed, just swap 0 to 255 by 255 to 0 below
  EXAMPLE:
  Normal:    data.ch1 = map( analogRead(A0), 0, 1024, 0, 255);
  Reversed:  data.ch1 = map( analogRead(A0), 0, 1024, 255, 0);  */
  
  sent_data.ch1 = map(analogRead(A1), 0, 1023, 0, 255);
  radio.write(&sent_data, sizeof(Data_to_be_sent));
  sent_data.ch2 = map(analogRead(A3), 0, 1023, 0, 255);
  radio.write(&sent_data, sizeof(Data_to_be_sent));
}



//Receiver-Code
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

const uint64_t pipeIn = 0xE8E8F0F0E7LL;     //veränderter
//const uint64_t pipeIn = 0xE8E80000E1LL; //echter
RF24 radio(9, 10);  //CSN and CE pins

// The sizeof this struct should not exceed 32 bytes
struct Received_data {
  byte ch1;
  byte ch2;
};

int ch1_value = 0;
int ch2_value = 0;
Received_data received_data;


/**************************************************/
//PIN-Deklaration
short enB = 5;
short enA = 6;
short in1 = 1;
short in2 = 2;
short in3 = 3;
short in4 = 4;

//Variablendeklaration
short linker;
short rechter;
short vLinker;
short vRechter;
short ivLinker;
short ivRechter;
short gem;
short gemRest;
short rest;
short mitte = 512;
short ober = 561;
short unter = 462;
short orest;
short urest;

void lV(){
  digitalWrite(enA,LOW);
  digitalWrite(in1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(enA,HIGH);
}

void lR(){
  digitalWrite(enA,LOW);
  digitalWrite(in1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(in2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(enA,HIGH);
}

void lF(){ //links aus / Leergang
  digitalWrite(enA,LOW);
}

void rV(){ //rechter Motor vorwärts
  digitalWrite(enB,LOW);
  digitalWrite(in3,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in4,LOW);
  digitalWrite(enB,HIGH);
}

void rR(){ //rechter Motor rückwärts
  digitalWrite(enB,LOW);
  digitalWrite(in3,LOW);
  digitalWrite(in4,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(enB,HIGH);
}

void rF(){ //rechts aus / Leergang
  digitalWrite(enB,LOW);
}

void lrF(){ //beide aus / Leergang
  digitalWrite(enA,LOW);
  digitalWrite(enB,LOW);
}

void setup(){

  Serial.begin(9600);

  //Pinfestlegung
  pinMode(enA,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enB,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in3,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in4,OUTPUT);
  
  //We reset the received values
  received_data.ch1 = 119;
  received_data.ch2 = 58;
 
  //Once again, begin and radio configuration
  radio.begin();
  radio.setAutoAck(false);
  radio.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS);  
  radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipeIn);
  
  //We start the radio comunication
  radio.startListening();

}

/**************************************************/

unsigned long last_Time = 0;

//We create the function that will read the data each certain time
void receive_the_data()
{
  while ( radio.available() ) {
  radio.read(&received_data, sizeof(Received_data));
  last_Time = millis(); //Here we receive the data
}
}

/**************************************************/



void loop(){




  while(true){ //!!!receiving two analog values, and storing them in left and right
     lrF();
     ch1_value = map(received_data.ch1,0,255,0,1023);
     ch2_value = map(received_data.ch2,0,255,0,1023);
     linker = ch1_value;
     rechter = ch2_value;
     Serial.print("left: ");
     Serial.println(left);
     Serial.print("right: ");
     Serial.println(right);
  } //why is the Serial print showing ramdom values, even if there should not be a transmission






  //beide vorerst aus
  lrF();
  linker = 512;
  rechter = 512;
  
  //Receive the radio data
  receive_the_data();

  //Übernahme der Analogreferenzwerte für beide Knüppel
  //ch1_value = received_data.ch1;
  ch1_value = map(received_data.ch1,0,255,0,1023);
  ch2_value = map(received_data.ch2,0,255,0,1023);
  //Überschreibung der Werte in Variablen links/rechts
  linker = ch1_value;
  rechter = ch2_value;

  for(int i = 200; i > 0; i--){ //PWM-Signalanlegung
    
  if((linker <= ober && linker >= unter) && (rechter <= ober && rechter >= unter)){ //Leergang
    lrF();
    delayMicroseconds(463);
  }

  if((rechter == linker) && (linker > ober)){ //geradeaus
    vLinker = linker - ober;
    gem = vLinker;
    rest = 463 - gem;
    lV();
    rV();
    delayMicroseconds(gem);
    lrF();
    delayMicroseconds(rest);

  }

  if((linker > ober) && (rechter > ober) && (linker > rechter)){ //linksvorwärts
    vLinker = linker - ober;
    vRechter = rechter - ober;
    gem = vRechter;
    gemRest = vLinker - vRechter;
    rest = 463 - gem - gemRest;
    rV();
    lV();
    delayMicroseconds(gem);
    lV();
    rF();
    delayMicroseconds(gemRest);
    lrF();
    delayMicroseconds(rest);
  }

  if((rechter > ober) && (linker > ober) && (rechter > linker)){ //rechtsvorwärts
    vLinker = linker - ober;
    vRechter = rechter - ober;
    gem = vLinker;
    gemRest = vRechter - vLinker;
    rest = 463 - gem - gemRest;
    rV();
    lV();
    delayMicroseconds(gem);
    rV();
    lF();
    delayMicroseconds(gemRest);
    lrF();
    delayMicroseconds(rest);
  }

  if((rechter == linker) && (linker < unter)){ //rückwärts
    vLinker = linker;
    ivLinker = 463 - linker;
    gem = ivLinker;
    rest = 463 - gem;
    lR();
    rR();
    delayMicroseconds(gem);
    lrF();
    delayMicroseconds(rest);
  }

  if((linker < unter) && (rechter < unter) && (rechter > linker)){ //linksrückwärts
    vLinker = linker;
    vRechter = rechter;
    ivRechter = 463 - rechter;
    ivLinker = 463 - linker;
    gem = ivRechter;
    gemRest = ivLinker - ivRechter;
    rest = 463 - gem - gemRest;
    lR();
    rR();
    delayMicroseconds(gem);
    lR();
    rF();
    delayMicroseconds(gemRest);
    lrF();
    delayMicroseconds(rest);
  }

  if((linker < unter) && (rechter < unter) && (rechter < linker)){ //rechtsrückwärts
    vLinker = linker;
    vRechter = rechter;
    ivRechter = 463 - rechter;
    ivLinker = 463 - linker;
    gem = ivLinker;
    gemRest = ivRechter - ivLinker;
    rest = 463 - gem - gemRest;
    lR();
    rR();
    delayMicroseconds(gem);
    rR();
    lF();
    delayMicroseconds(gemRest);
    lrF();
    delayMicroseconds(rest);
  }

  if((linker < unter) && (rechter > ober) && (463 - linker >= rechter - ober)){ //linker rück rück, rechter vor   
    ivLinker = 463 - linker;
    vRechter = rechter - ober;
    gem = vRechter;
    gemRest = ivLinker - vRechter;
    rest = 463 - gem - gemRest;
    lR();
    rV();
    delayMicroseconds(gem);
    lR();
    rF();
    delayMicroseconds(gemRest);
    lrF();
    delayMicroseconds(rest);
  }

  if((linker < unter) && (rechter > ober) && (463 - linker < rechter - ober)){ //linker rück, rechter vor vor
    ivLinker = 463 - linker;
    vRechter = rechter - ober;
    gem = ivLinker;
    gemRest = vRechter - ivLinker;
    rest = 463 - gem - gemRest;
    rV();
    lR();
    delayMicroseconds(gem);
    rV();
    lF();
    delayMicroseconds(gemRest);
    lrF();
    delayMicroseconds(rest);
  }

  if((linker > ober) && (rechter < unter) && (463 - rechter <= linker - ober)){ //linker vor vor, rechter rück
    ivRechter = 463 - rechter;
    vLinker = linker - ober;
    gem = ivRechter;
    gemRest = vLinker - ivRechter;
    rest = 463 - gem - gemRest;
    lV();
    rR();
    delayMicroseconds(gem);
    lV();
    rF();
    delayMicroseconds(gemRest);
    lrF();
    delayMicroseconds(rest);
  }
  
  if((linker > ober) && (rechter < unter) && (463 - rechter > linker - ober)){ //linker vor, rechter rück rück
    ivRechter = 463 - rechter;
    vLinker = linker - ober;
    gem = vLinker;
    gemRest = ivRechter - vLinker;
    rest = 463 - gem - gemRest;
    rR();
    lV();
    delayMicroseconds(gem);
    rR();
    lF();
    delayMicroseconds(gemRest);
    lrF();
    delayMicroseconds(rest);
  }

  if((linker > ober) && (rechter > unter) && (rechter < ober)){ //linker allein vor
    vLinker = linker - ober;
    gem = vLinker;
    rest = 463 - vLinker;
    lV();
    rF();
    delayMicroseconds(gem);
    lrF();
    delayMicroseconds(rest);
  }

  if((rechter > ober) && (linker > unter) && (linker < ober)){ //rechter alleine vor
    vRechter = rechter - ober;
    gem = vRechter;
    rest = 463 - vRechter;
    rV();
    lF();
    delayMicroseconds(gem);
    lrF();
    delayMicroseconds(rest);
  }

  if((linker < unter) && (rechter > unter) && (rechter < ober)){ //linker alleine rück
    ivLinker = 463 - linker;
    gem = ivLinker;
    rest = 463 - ivLinker;
    lR();
    rF();
    delayMicroseconds(gem);
    lrF();
    delayMicroseconds(rest);
  }

  if((rechter < unter) && (linker > unter) && (linker < ober)){ //rechter alleine rück
    ivRechter = 463 - rechter;
    gem = ivRechter;
    rest = 463 - ivRechter;
    rR();
    lF();
    delayMicroseconds(gem);
    lrF();
    delayMicroseconds(rest);
  }
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Transmit a checksum with your data. If the checksum doesn't check out then it's garbage and you throw it away, setting your "no signal" values in the process.

Comment: Add a 10K ohm resistor between each pin and the GND pin to avoid them floating.